# Should I mention QA experience in my CV for a first software development position?

Tags: resume, software-development

I recently graduated from university after studying computer science. I do not possess any professional experience in software development. In this case, is it worth mentioning QA experience (less than two years) in my CV?

Note: this QA experience corresponds to working in QA in a big software corporate (exposure to the industry).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should my resume list work experience from unrelated fields?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/55775/should-my-resume-list-work-experience-from-unrelated-fields)

Comment: Except that software QA is is very  much related to software development.  In really small companies, the developers often do both development and QA.

Comment: @Dukeling though it is answering my question to some extent, I think that 17 of 26's answer is more informative in this specific case.

Comment: It's worth noting that in Agile development frameworks like Scrum, Developers are "cross functional" and the distinction between "coder" and "qa guy" is ideally eliminated.

Comment: @Mystagogue I disagree.  Development and QA are distinctly different skill sets.

Comment: @17of26 You can choose to disagree, but that's how it's done in Scrum. The development team is all T-shaped developers.

Comment: There's nothing in the Scrum process that dictates that your team members all have the same exact job function.  I've worked in companies where we did Scrum and had separate devs and QA co-existing in a Scrum team..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.

The QA job gave you experience with testing and the software development process.

Those are both very relevant to a software developer and you will be a better candidate than a college grad without any experience.

Comment: Especially if you can link it back to the job requirements.  "Because of my QA background, I know what a finished product should look like when it's ready to go into production," etc.